# Default values for boto3 method parameters

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, emr, boto3

I would like to programmatically write a method that calls a boto3 method and change default parameters inside methods.

For example, I want to use my log bucket if log is set to True. Otherwise, don't log it. Something like this:

```
def my_run(log=False):
    log_string = "s3://mylogs" if log else None

    result = emr.run_job_flow(Name   = 'EMRTest1',
                              LogUri = log_string ,
                              ...
                              )
    return result
```

So, for default value I used None. However, boto3 expects a string. I tried empty string for default and it's not a valid value

I know that if I don't specify logURI, it won't get stored. So I could do it with if statements, like this:

```
def my_run(log=False):
    if log:
        result = emr.run_job_flow(Name   = 'EMRTest1',
                                  LogUri = "s3://mylogs" ,
                                  ...
                                  )
    else:
        result = emr.run_job_flow(Name   = 'EMRTest1',
                                  ...
                                  )
    return result
```

But that's horrible way. And LogUri was just an example. I want to be able to change other parameters. I just can't make those nested ifs.

Is there a default value for various types like strings in boto3 that I can use?

---

Edit 1

From the first comment below, 
http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/events.html#provide-client-params

Interesting API. Not well documented though. Their example for s3 clisnt works fine,

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

# Access the event system on the S3 client
event_system = s3.meta.events

# Create a function
def add_my_bucket(params, **kwargs):
    print "Hello"
    # Add the name of the bucket you want to default to.
    if 'Bucket' not in params:
        params['Bucket'] = 'mybucket'

# Register the function to an event
event_system.register('provide-client-params.s3.ListObjects', add_my_bucket)

response = s3.list_objects()
```

then response is good and also I see "Hello" printed.

But now I try to make an example for emr's run_job_flow:

```
def my_run(name):
    def setName(params, **kwargs):
        print "Hello"
        params['Name'] = name

    current_emr  = boto3.client('emr')
    event_system = current_emr.meta.events

    event_system.register('provide-client-params.emr.RunJobFlow', setName)

    current_emr.run_job_flow(...)
```

When I run this, I get:
Missing required parameter in input: "Name"

Am I using wrong syntax somehow?
I did use RunJobFlow which I got from current_emr.meta.method_to_api_mapping
Maybe it's not provide-client-params for emr?

I also don't see "Hello" printed

Answer (score 1):

There are no default values except the service specified ones, in which case we just send nothing at all. If you want to change parameters at run-time you can hook into the events system. You can read up about that [here](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/events.html#an-introduction-to-the-event-system). The examples there are pretty close to what I think you want to do.